# Update your browser to use Google Maps when opening a google map within a SimpleSwingBrowser

Tags: java, swing, javafx, maps

am trying to open a google maps link within a java application. came across the sample code below tried it out and it loads the map perfectly but then after loading is done the page shows "Update your browser to use Google Maps" message and the map closes.

using jdk 1.8, GMapsFX-2.12.0 on Netbeans IDE 8.2

point me in the right direction.. tnxs in advance.

Here is my code

```
    package com.lynden.SimpleSwingBrowser;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import javafx.application.Platform;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import static javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.FAILED;
    import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
    import javax.swing.*;

    /**
     *
     * @author User
     */
    public class SimpleSwingBrowser implements Runnable {
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
    private WebEngine engine;

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel();

    private JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go");
    private JTextField txtURL = new JTextField();
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    private void initComponents() {
        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        createScene();

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loadURL(txtURL.getText());
            }
        };

        btnGo.addActionListener(al);
        txtURL.addActionListener(al);

        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 18));
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel topBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        topBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        topBar.add(txtURL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topBar.add(btnGo, BorderLayout.EAST);


        JPanel statusBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        statusBar.add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        statusBar.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panel.add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();

            

engine.titleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String `oldValue, final String newValue) {`
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            frame.setTitle(newValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

                engine.setOnStatusChanged(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
                    @Override public void handle(final WebEvent<String> event) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                lblStatus.setText(event.getData());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            

engine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, final `String newValue) {`
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            txtURL.setText(newValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            

engine.getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number `oldValue, final Number newValue) {`
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            progressBar.setValue(newValue.intValue());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            

engine.getLoadWorker()
                    .exceptionProperty()
                    .addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {

                        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> o, Throwable `old, final Throwable value) {`
                            if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() == FAILED) {
                                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override public void run() {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                                panel,
                                                (value != null) ?
                                                engine.getLocation() + "\n" + value.getMessage() :
                                                engine.getLocation() + "\nUnexpected error.",
                                                "Loading error...",
                                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });

            jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
        }
    });
}

 

public void loadURL(final String url) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            String tmp = toURL(url);

            if (tmp == null) {
                tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
            }

            engine.load(tmp);
        }
    });
}

private static String toURL(String str) {
    try {
        return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
    } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            return null;
    }
}

        @Override public void run() {
    
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
            initComponents();
    
        
    
    loadURL("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/7.0685289,38.4791676/Teticha+Health+Center,+Teticha/Awaye+Kararo+Health+Center/Mejo+Primary+Hospital,+Bubbe/7.0685289,38.4791676/@6.6555334,38.4639454,11z/data=!4m24!4m23!1m1!4e1!1m5!1m1!1s0x17b0d1ddc537e75b:0x8f01bdf3b440d3ac!2m2!1d38.5331294!2d6.5576005!1m5!1m1!1s0x17b733852eccaa3f:0x888346f55e085a32!2m2!1d38.7300855!2d6.435249!1m5!1m1!1s0x17b73fb931e23413:0xd0d5830b9b7b12dc!2m2!1d38.9510496!2d6.3811229!1m1!4e1!3e0");
    
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleSwingBrowser());
        }
    }
```

Comment: My guess is the online google maps isn't supported for WebView? That's where I would look. Google also has a maps API which may be worth looking into. Also side note, it seems weird to used both JavaFx and Swing here. Why not fully commit to FX.

Comment: I tried to open "https://www.google.com/maps" in a JavaFX 19 (OS X) WebView.  I didn't see a message "Update your browser to use Google Maps" message, however, the page did not display a map either.  I think @M.Rogers is correct that the current version of Google maps is incompatible with WebView.  This is likely an issue that only Google and/or a JavaFX system developer can fix.

Comment: It's possible that google maps checks the browser and version against a list of known browsers and supported apps. If that's the case, you may be able to convince google that web view is supported by setting the user agent on the web engine to make it appear to be, e.g., Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head to a wall for hours, i updated jdk to jdk 19 but i guess jdk 19 doesn't include dependencies for javafx so i included the libraries in the image below and all is guchi now.

[image]

Thanks all.